# XML Parser for C

Tags: c, xml, parsing

Can you suggest some of the best XML Parser for C ?

Comment: Define "best". Fastest? Easiest to use (certainly libxml2)? More portable? Most widely available?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Two of the most widely used parsers are [Expat](http://www.jclark.com/xml/expat.html) and [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/).

If you are okay with using C++, there's [Xerces-C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) too.

Answer (score 77):

Two examples with [expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net) and [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/). The second one is,
IMHO, much easier to use since it creates a tree in memory, a data
structure which is easy to work with. expat, on the other hand, does
not build anything (you have to do it yourself), it just allows you to
call handlers at specific events during the parsing. But expat may be
faster (I didn't measure).

With expat, reading a XML file and displaying the elements indented:

```
/* 
   A simple test program to parse XML documents with expat
   <http://expat.sourceforge.net/>. It just displays the element
   names.

   On Debian, compile with:

   gcc -Wall -o expat-test -lexpat expat-test.c  

   Inspired from <http://www.xml.com/pub/a/1999/09/expat/index.html> 
*/

#include <expat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Keep track of the current level in the XML tree */
int             Depth;

#define MAXCHARS 1000000

void
start(void *data, const char *el, const char **attr)
{
    int             i;

    for (i = 0; i < Depth; i++)
        printf("  ");

    printf("%s", el);

    for (i = 0; attr[i]; i += 2) {
        printf(" %s='%s'", attr[i], attr[i + 1]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    Depth++;
}               /* End of start handler */

void
end(void *data, const char *el)
{
    Depth--;
}               /* End of end handler */

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char           *filename;
    FILE           *f;
    size_t          size;
    char           *xmltext;
    XML_Parser      parser;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return (1);
    }
    filename = argv[1];
    parser = XML_ParserCreate(NULL);
    if (parser == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Parser not created\n");
        return (1);
    }
    /* Tell expat to use functions start() and end() each times it encounters
     * the start or end of an element. */
    XML_SetElementHandler(parser, start, end);
    f = fopen(filename, "r");
    xmltext = malloc(MAXCHARS);
    /* Slurp the XML file in the buffer xmltext */
    size = fread(xmltext, sizeof(char), MAXCHARS, f);
    if (XML_Parse(parser, xmltext, strlen(xmltext), XML_TRUE) ==
        XML_STATUS_ERROR) {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Cannot parse %s, file may be too large or not well-formed XML\n",
            filename);
        return (1);
    }
    fclose(f);
    XML_ParserFree(parser);
    fprintf(stdout, "Successfully parsed %i characters in file %s\n", size,
        filename);
    return (0);
}
```

With libxml2, a program which displays the name of the root element
and the names of its children:

```
/*
   Simple test with libxml2 <http://xmlsoft.org>. It displays the name
   of the root element and the names of all its children (not
   descendents, just children).

   On Debian, compiles with:
   gcc -Wall -o read-xml2 $(xml2-config --cflags) $(xml2-config --libs) \
                    read-xml2.c    

*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    xmlDoc         *document;
    xmlNode        *root, *first_child, *node;
    char           *filename;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s filename.xml\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    filename = argv[1];

    document = xmlReadFile(filename, NULL, 0);
    root = xmlDocGetRootElement(document);
    fprintf(stdout, "Root is <%s> (%i)\n", root->name, root->type);
    first_child = root->children;
    for (node = first_child; node; node = node->next) {
        fprintf(stdout, "\t Child is <%s> (%i)\n", node->name, node->type);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for good examples with the command to compile.

Comment: for your `libxml2` example, I think you should be calling `xmlFreeDoc(document);` when you are finished parsing.

Comment: I just had to add `-lxml2` at the end of that command to make it work.

Comment: how to compile this program? i am getting undefined reference error for functions in this program. what is the command to run this program...-> gcc -o filename filename.c -IC:\Users\admin\Desktop\Expat\Source\lib ... i am getting undefined reference error...

Answer (score 45):

How about one written in [pure assembler](http://mkerbiquet.free.fr/asm-xml/) :-) Don't forget to check out the [benchmarks](http://mkerbiquet.free.fr/asm-xml/benchmark.html).

Comment: Nice, you win. :-)

Comment: Much of the speed factor comes from the fact that it only supports a subset of XML but it looks like it may be useful for many purposes.  Very neat.

Comment: Not having used it, I can't really recommend it, but thought it was worth sharing since it does have a C API :)

Comment: Now that looks really, REALLY interesting for tasks where the schema and name space is known (i.e. RSS). Thanks for the link!!

Comment: Tip: I had a problem where my document's root (a format I have no control over) contained a sub-element instead of a collection directly thereunder, so it didn't match the example the author gives in the [Tutorial](http://tibleiz.net/asm-xml/tutorial.html). For such a situation: `AXParseContext context;
 ax_initializeParser(&context, 16384);
 AXElement* root = ax_parse(&context, xmlPtr, rootClass, 1);
 AXElement* first = (AXElement*) root->attributes[0].begin;` Note specifically use of `root->attributes[0].begin`, which is a pointer to an `AXElement`, NOT `root->firstChild` as in tutorial.

Comment: Sadly ASM XML does not support 64-bit so it's a no go on macOS.

Comment: based and red pilled.

Answer (score 10):

You can try [ezxml](http://ezxml.sourceforge.net/) -- it's a lightweight parser written entirely in C.

For C++ you can check out [TinyXML++](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/)

Answer (score 7):

http://www.minixml.org is also pretty good.  Small and just ANSI C.

Answer (score 4):

My personal preference is [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/). It's very easy to use but I never bothered to benchmark it, as I've only used it for configuration file parsing.

Answer (score 2):

[Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net) is pretty decent. It's hard to give good recommendations without more information though.

Answer (score 2):

Could you give some indication of what platforms you are writing for? This should weigh heavily on what is 'best'. You might find a super 'xml-foo' library that does not ship commonly on most systems by default .. while its great, the lack of the library might prevent (or at least) annoy users.

Mostly, I use libxml2 .. because its standard or easy to install on the platforms that I target.

As you see, 'best' is also determined by the library being available on your target platforms.

Answer (score 2):

For C++ I suggest using [CMarkup](http://www.firstobject.com).

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, it's native with Win32 api...

Comment: just for the sake of completeness I'd like to add this for Windows: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/data-misc/xml/article.php/c4549