# Accessing data in xml using C

Tags: c, xml, parsing

I have parsed a basic xml document with the following format

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <title>sometitle</title>
    <keyword>example keyword</keyword>
  <body>
    <headline>headline</headline>
    <para>body text.</para>
  </body>
</data>
```

and it works correctly.

My issue is trying to access data within a single `< >` like so

```
<tileset firstgid="1" name="testSet" tilewidth="20" tileheight="20" spacing="1" margin="1">
   <image source="Tile.png" width="265" height="199"/>
</tileset>
```

How does one access e.g. 1 from firstgid or testSet from name ?

Comment: Have you ever heard of XPath or are you looking for something else? It's not clear to me from the question

Comment: I have heard of it but never used it. Will it allow this access?

Comment: Yes - I've added a link to a tutorial in my answer below. Good luck!

Comment: @Paddyslacker: Thanks, I will have a look.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399704/xml-parser-for-c/399705#399705

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are attributes and you would use `@` within your xpath:

```
/tileset/@firstgid
```

or

```
/tileset/@name
```

Comment: This worked thanks. So, using libxml, will a new xPath pointer be created for each different node wanted, and then go through each node to get the data?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp). It will allow you to access the data in the XML tree in many different ways. There are slightly different (language specific) implementations, so precisely how you would use XPath depends upon the language you are using to work with XML, but the XPath *syntax* pretty much stays the same in each language.