# how to parse/extract some info out of an xml file in C

Tags: c, xml-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML Parser for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399704/xml-parser-for-c)

Hello there 
I need some quick help on how to parse/extract information out of an XML file using C.

The project I am trying to work on is just for personal learning. I'm trying to learn C on my own. I am trying to write a program that will search about spacefic text or the name of the  author   from a pregenerated XML config file.

Below is a copy of what my XML looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<config>
    <quote>
    <text>
        "Moral indignation is jealous with a halo."
    </text>
    <author>
        H.G. Wells
    </author>
    <livedfrom>
        1866-1946
    </livedfrom>
    <extrainfo />
</quote>
```

If someone can just help me get started or direct me to some reading material online or tutorial, I would greatly appreciate.

Thanks,

Comment: http://www.xmlsoft.org/

Comment: Learning C by starting with processing XML files is quite ambitious. Buy a good C book and work through that first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML Parser for C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399704/xml-parser-for-c)

Comment: The dup may not be what you want, but it's still a dup ;) If it's for your learning purpose as you say, you'd be better off trying to read/write a plain text file before jumping onto xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested also in C++ you may try rapidxml:

http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/

http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html

Here, I've written an example code that parses & prints the content of a xml with a depth of three levels (as yours):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "./rapidxml-1.13/rapidxml.hpp"
#include "./rapidxml-1.13/rapidxml_print.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace rapidxml;


void process_xml(const char* xml){
    xml_document<> doc;
    char text[strlen(xml)+1];
    strcpy(&text[0], xml);
    try{
        doc.parse<parse_default>(text);
    }
    catch(rapidxml::parse_error &ex){
        cout << "error: rapidxml::parse_error\n";
        return;
    }

    xml_node<> *ptr=NULL;
    try{
        if (doc.first_node()!=NULL){
            for (xml_node<> *node=doc.first_node(); node; node=node->next_sibling()){
                cout << "node->name: " << node->name() << endl;
                if (strcmp(node->name(), "")!=0){
                    xml_node<> *content_node = node->first_node();
                    ptr=content_node;
                    while ((content_node!=NULL) && (strcmp(content_node->name(), "")!=0)){
                        cout << "\t>>" << content_node->name() << endl;

                        for (xml_node<> *node_3rd=content_node->first_node(); node_3rd; node_3rd=node_3rd->next_sibling()){
                            cout << "name: " << node_3rd->name() << "; ";
                            cout << "value: " << node_3rd->value() << endl;
                        }

                        content_node=content_node->next_sibling();
                    }
                }
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }
    catch(...){
        cout << "error: in reading an event!";
    }
}


int main(void){
    //read the xml from an input file
    std::ifstream ifs("in_file.txt");
    std::string xml;
    xml.assign(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    //process the xml
    process_xml(xml.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

- notice: to turn your xml into a valid xml you must close all your tags, so you should add `</config>` at the end, because you have `<config>` at the beginning.

To run this code you have to download rapidxml from the link that I provided and put it unziped in your project folder. The compilation doesn't require additional flags.

Then, with an input file "in_file.txt" with your corrected xml (*see the notice above), this code will produce as output:

```
node->name: config
    >>quote
name: text; value: 
            "Moral indignation is jealous with a halo."

name: author; value: 
            H.G. Wells

name: livedfrom; value: 
            1866-1946

name: extrainfo; value:
```

Then, you can store the resulting values in variables, structs or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

In any case this will come down to the art of parsing text. You should read up on formal grammars and maybe look into how to build a simple parser using Flex and Bison.

Otherwise a classical way of building a parser is to do what is called a recursive decent parser using one look ahead token.

However a parser always works on tandem with a tokenizer. The tokenizers task is to transform certain strings of characters into tokens (usually implemented as numerical values). The tokes often carry the string (or some value (not the token value) that was generated from the string, e.g. some numeric constant) which it was generated from so the parser can take proper action. Regular expressions are usually used to tell the tokenizer what string to convert to what token.

So back again to the recursive decent parser. It essence it looks something like the following code. But check for example [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) for more information.

```
void handle_token_foo()
{
  //Do something now when we know we handle token FOO
  ....
  //Find next token and take appropriate action
  Token t = tokenizer.get_next_token();
  if(t == TOKEN_TYPE_BAR)
  {
    parse_token_bar();  
  }
  else if(t == TOKEN_TYPE_FOO)
  {
    parse_token_foo();
  }
  else if(t == TOKEN_TYPE_END)
  {
     return;
  }
  throw ParseError();
  return 
}

void handle_token_bar()
{
  //Do something now when we know we handle token BAR
  ....
  //Find next token and take appropriate action

  Token t = tokenizer.get_next_token();
  if(t == TOKEN_TYPE_BAR)
  {
    parse_token_bar();  
  }
  else if(t == TOKEN_TYPE_FOO)
  {
    parse_token_foo();
  }
  else if(t == TOKEN_TYPE_END)
  {
     return;
  }
  throw ParseError();
  return;
}
```

The "Do something part" can maybe push values and operators on a stack to implement some form of [Shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). Or build an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

However there is also a nice library in Boost `boost::spirit` that can be used to build parsers.

So on the other hand if you just want an XML parser there are a number of ready made to choose from. Have seen some nice flow chart here on SO that describes witch XML parser is good depending on your requirements.