# Reading an OpenOffice file in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, openoffice.org, dev-c++

I am curious as to how I might be able to use my compiler to open OpenOffice documents. I know I could probably convert it into a text file or rtf but I wonder if it is possible to read straight from the .odt. What I am trying to do is simply read line by line much like a .txt file would. Any ideas would be nice, I am using DevC if that helps.

Comment: `.odt` files are zipped archives of a directory containing notably XML files. Try to `unzip` some `.odt` file first to get an idea what it contains...

Comment: The compiler won't do that. Are you trying to write a program that reads OO files, or do you want your compiler to compile code that you wrote in .odt?

Answer (score 4):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument_technical_specification#Format_internals), a *.odt* file is simply a standard ZIP archive consisting of the following:

- **XML files:**

  - content.xml
  - meta.xml
  - settings.xml
  - styles.xml
- **Other files**:

  - mimetype
  - Directories
  - **META-INF/**:

    - manifest.xml
  - **Thumbnails/**:

    - thumbnail.png

Content.xml will have the contents of the file (for info on the other files, refer to the [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument_technical_specification#Format_internals) above). You can use any XML library to parse that XML file (and the others) to read the data. All your program would need to do is to unzip the *.odt* file, then pass whatever XML file you want to parse to the XML library.

Examples of XML libraries you can use are mentioned in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/399705/1383051).

For unzipping the *.odt* file, you have some decent options:

- libzip as suggested by [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10440251/1383051).
- [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html)

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be C/C++?  Linux Journal did a good write-up on parsing an ODT file with Python.

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9347

The idea will be the same, just different libraries to do the heavy lifting.