# XMLFile parsing using file operations

Tags: c++

I am trying to write XML parser using file operations and I got the pointer of the XML file. I am trying to read character by character using fgetc function but it is not working.

```
std::string sFileName = "C:\\Users\\simple\\Desktop\\XMLFile.xml";
std::string sTempstring;
char cXML;
FILE *fptr;
fptr = fopen(sFileName.c_str(),"r");
fseek(fptr, 0L, SEEK_END);
long int iLength = ftell(fptr);
const int bufSize = 412;

char* tempdata = new char[iLength]();
if (fptr != NULL)
{
    int i = 0;
    while ((cXML = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF)
    {
        cout << cXML;
        i++;
    }
    sTempstring.append(tempdata);
    cout << sTempstring.c_str();

}
else
{
    cout << "File is empty";
}
getchar();
return 0;
```

Please let me know what mistake I am doing.
 XML information i want to store that in some string by reading the xml file using file operations so i have written above function

Comment: _"but it is not working"_ is a very vague problem description. Post a [mcve] as required here please.

Comment: XMLinfo:
    <note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>

Comment: That is the XML information i want to store that in some string by reading that xml file using file operations

Comment: Post additional information in your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22576675) please.

Comment: please provide me solution to read XML information and to store in some string. how can i achieve this using c language

Comment: And don't spam tags, your code is obviously not c related. There are no such things like `cout` in c language.

Comment: I suggest using an actual XML parsing library (plenty are available for C++), and not try to do this yourself with some home-made code.  There are too many corner cases that can happen that your code could miss.

Comment: The ideology is purely C.  If C++ is available, you'll have std::string and a wide array of tools C doesn't have. I highly recommend you make use of them.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings. Read them carefully.

Comment: As an educational experience, writing an XML parser is worth the time spent. It's a fairly hard project, though.

Comment: sure i have to use this code using c languge where the existing dlls cant be used in that environiment

Comment: Write the guts of the DLL in C++. Provide the DLL's interface in C. Your life will be much easier.

Comment: @rajee _"how can i achieve this using c language"_ So you think you have something working in c++ and want to convert it to plain c code? I'm really lost about what you're actually asking about.

Comment: @rajee XML parsing is surprisingly complex given the plain definition of XML. I'd recommend to [use a library supporting a c-API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399704/xml-parser-for-c) instead of writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
fptr = fopen(sFileName.c_str(),"r");
fseek(fptr, 0L, SEEK_END);
long int iLength = ftell(fptr);
fseek(fptr, 0L, SEEK_SET);
```

add **fseek(fptr, 0L, SEEK_SET)** specific location.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/ 
Hope your study successfully done.