# How to check if line in xml file has specific tag and if found save value within tag in c

Tags: c, xml, fopen, fgets

So I am quite new to c programming and was wondering whether there is a way to read through an xml file line by line and save the value between a tag if found.

So far I have created the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

  char line [150];
  FILE *file = fopen("testfile.xml","r");
  if (file == NULL) {
    fprintf(stdout,"Unable to open file.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
   
  while(fgets(ln, sizeof(ln), file)) {
    fprintf(stdout,"%s\n",ln);
  }

  return (0);
}
```

This is an example of how my xml file looks. Multiple tags can be on the same line.

```
<Details>
<firstname>Steve</firstname>
<surname>Barrat</surname>
<age>20</age>
<info><addr>23 Boxwell road</addr><hobby>Football</hobby></info>
</Details>
```

Is there any method in which I can check if for example `<addr>` tag exists in the line read and if
so, save value from the content of that tag to a variable.

Any help would be great.

Comment: The usual method would be to use a xml-parser lib. Does anything prevent you from doing that?

Comment: @Yunnosch. I am unfamiliar with that as I only recently learnt c programming. I will take a look.

Comment: You might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/407642/898348

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to read an XML file line-by-line because line breaks can occur anywhere, for example your file might be formatted as

```
    <Details><firstname
>Steve</firstname><surname>Barrat</surname
><age>20</age><info><addr>23 Boxwell road</addr><hobby>Football</hobby></info>
    </Details>
```

and you would still be expected to read it successfully. You should be reading it element-by-element, not line-by-line, and the tool you use to do so is an XML parser.

I'm afraid I'm not up to speed with the state of the art in XML parsing from C, beyond the fact that most people use libxml; more modern languages such as Java and C# are much better served.